# To partner with Instagram action buttons

Tags: instagram

I am working on food ordering website and  I want to be a partner with Instagram for Action buttons.
How can I do this similar to yelp? Is there any API or have to contact Instagram for being a partner.

My requirement is to provide start order button to our restaurants on instagram